# Set the default active item before rendering the component based on its id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My goal is to highlight the first element in the `results` array before rendering the component. When the user sees the component, the first element will be active. I did it in the `componentDidMount ()` method. Immediately on the returned answer, I chose the `id` of the first element`res.data [0].id`. Are there any other ways to get the `id` of the first element of the array, so that you do not immediately operate on`response`? I note that on the basis of this `id` I designate a link that will be active by default before rendering the component.

```
 componentDidMount() {  
    axios.get
        axios({
            url,
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
              'Authorization': ``
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
              results: res.data,
              activeItem: res.data[0].id 
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })      
}
```

Comment: Why exactly are you unhappy with your current solution?

Comment: @ChrisG   I do not like that if I add `socket.io`. Data is fetch every few minutes. After clicking on the link it returns to the default set in setState ({})

Comment: So why *do* you reset the state to `{}` when the link is clicked? Just don't do that. Sorry, but unless you show code, we can't really help with this. Please make sure the question above is your actual question.